# Is it possible to communicate with a facebook app by tagging it in posts?

Tags: facebook, tags, comments

I've been trying to find a way to receive commands from my app's users, and haven't been able to find any. Ideally, I'd like the user to be able to tag the app or a page in a post or a comment, get a notification and process the command. However, there doesn't appear to be a way to retrieve tags for an application, and no matter what I try for a page, the 'tags' connection is always empty (but does return data for my test user account).

Is there any way to do this? Even with the `read_stream` permission, I can only see the posts made by my user, but I don't see the comments left on their friends's pages.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible via an api notification. You will have to process the body of the message and look for the tags and the commands using some regex

For example Hubot does this in IRC and Twitter.

https://github.com/MathildeLemee/hubot-twitter/blob/master/src/twitter.coffee

Comment: I can't get to the message, which is the problem. The tags themselves are actually part of the json returned via the graph api.

Comment: @SergeyIvanyuk you should be able to find the posts using the `/posts` endpoint under the `story` or `message` field

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I tried that, it only gives me the posts made by my user, or comments left by that user on their posts or posts of users that already have the app installed. I thought tagging a page would work, but no matter what I try I get back empty results. Basically I want to get to the point of implementing a bot, but the API isn't cooperating.

Comment: @SergeyIvanyuk yes it seems you are right. Not sure if that was intended.